# onMessage of MessageListener class is not called in groovy

Tags: groovy, jms

Here is my consumer code. Here i am trying to listen continuously to a queue and whan the message comes i try to send a reply to another queue. But here when i setMessageListener , my on Message code is not called.

```
import groovyjarjarantlr.debug.MessageEvent;
import groovyjarjarantlr.debug.MessageListener;
import groovyjarjarantlr.debug.TraceEvent;
import groovyjarjarasm.asm.Context

@Grab(group='net.sf.gtools.jms', module='JmsCategory', version='0.2')
@Grab(group='org.apache.activemq',module = 'activemq-all', version='5.9.0')
@Grab(group="junit", module="junit", version="4.11")

import javax.jms.Session
import javax.naming.InitialContext

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.apache.ivy.util.Message;

def connFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://pass-dev01.unx.sas.com:61616")

def conn = connFactory.createConnection()

def sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

def dest = sess.createQueue("pass-dev00.async")

def cons = sess.createConsumer(dest)
javax.jms.MessageListener listener
conn.start()
cons.setMessageListener(listener);

conn.close()

public abstract class JMSMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {

       println("in onmessage")

       def msg1 = cons.receive()
       println(msg1)

       //  def sendMessage() {
       Properties props = new Properties()
       File propsFile = new File('C:/workspace-grails/gateListener/src/gateListener/pass.hypervisor.properties')
       props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
       // println props.getProperty('pass.async.queue')
       def queueName=props.getProperty('pass.send.queue')
       println "sender"+queueName

       use(JmsCategory) {
          def jms = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory('tcp://pass-dev01.unx.sas.com:61616')
          jms.connect { c ->
             c.queue(queueName) { q ->
                def msg = createTextMessage("test")
                q.send(msg)
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if anyone has solution for this.

Comment: And... you never instantiate the `listener` variable?

Comment: i tried using this 'cons.setMessageListener(new JMSMessageListener().onMessage(msg1.text()));'. It never calls onMessage by whatever you try. listener variable i actually an interface, i cannot instantiate it.

Comment: Shouldn't the `listener` line be `listener = new JMSMessageListener()`, and the `JMSMessageListener` non abstract?  You seem to be setting a null message listener. I'm no JMS expert, but i'd expect this to throw a nullpointer

Comment: I tried using that earlier as : 'cons.setMessageListener(new JMSMessageListener());'  , it does not work. It just waits there,it never calls onMessage().

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed, i was importing the wrong library. I had to use JMS Listerner library `import javax.jms.MessageListener` instead of Groovy Message Listener.

Also i have to pass the obkject of the class that is implementing listener as :
`cons.setMessageListener(new JMSListener());` and this works. It calls onMessage